# Slim - Use variables of a route inside an included file

Tags: php, templates, routes, slim, slim-3

I'm using [Slim 3](https://www.slimframework.com/) to build an application.

In a certain route, I include via `include_once` the header of the template(*slim/php-view 2.2*), and there is some variables that I send to the template that I need to use in the header.

**Is there a way to do this?**

My route:

```
$app->get('/', function ( $request,  $response) {
    // some code here...
    $somedata = ' this is just a test';

    return $this->renderer->render($response, "/home.phtml",[
        'somedata' => $somedata,
    ]);
})
```

The target template(`home.phtml`):

```
<?php include_once('myheader.php'); ?>

    <h1>This is my template</h1>
    <p> I need to use this variable <?=$somedata?> 
    in the included myheader.php file</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. Reading [the docs](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View#template-variables) I found that I can achieve what I want using *template variables*, like this:

my route:

```
$templateVariables = [
    "title" => "Title"
];
$phpView = new PhpRenderer("./path/to/templates", $templateVariables);
```

my included file(`myheader.php`):

```
<?php echo $title ?>
```